# Why does British Indian Ocean Territory follow RHT?

Tags: united-kingdom, history, transportation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-_and_right-hand_traffic

Why do cars in the British Indian Ocean Territory drive on the right-hand side of the road (as in the US) instead of on the left-hand side of the road (like in Britain)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

British Indian Ocean Territory isn't very "British", nor is it very "Indian".

In the late 60s and early 70s the native people were expelled and now the only inhabitants are American service personnel.  The islands are now de facto American territory, as the only human activity is the US base. The only motor vehicles are US military vehicles. There is no civilian government, as there are no civilians there.

As a functionally *American* territory, it is unsurprising that the traffic runs on the right of the street.